# Кнопка в кнопке php

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Пишу код на добавление строчки в базу. Хочу сделать две кнопки, после нажатия первой показываются данные, и появляется вторая кнопка, с текстом "вы уверены, что хотите добавить эти данные в таблицу?"
Но после нажатия второй кнопки форма страницы очищается, и данные не заносятся. Как правильней расположить эти две кнопки? Код ниже

```
echo '<form method="post" class="update">
    <input type="text" name="id_book" size="10" value="">
    <button type="submit" name="addid">Добавить наименование</button></form>';
    if (isset($_POST['addid'])) 
    {
    //Код первой кнопки, отрабатывает хорошо
    echo 'Заносим эти данные? <form method="post" class="update">
    <button type="submit" name="addbase">Да</button></form>';
    if (isset($_POST['addbase'])) 
        {
        echo 'код второй кнопки';
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело не в расположении кнопок, а их обработке. Вытащите обработку второй кнопки из первого условного оператора.

```
if (isset($_POST['addid'])) 
{
    //Код первой кнопки, отрабатывает хорошо
    echo 'Заносим эти данные? <form method="post" class="update">
    <button type="submit" name="addbase">Да</button></form>';
}
if (isset($_POST['addbase'])) 
    {
    echo 'код второй кнопки';
    } 
}
```